# Get neo4j's internal unique ID with cyper and assign it to my object

Tags: .net, neo4j, cypher

I'm creating a new object like this, which has at this point a placeholder id:

```
    var query = client.Cypher
    .Create("(e:Example{newExample})")
    .WithParam("newExample", newExample)
    .Return(e =>  e.As<Example>())
    .Results;
```

But my object needs a unique id, which I need to request it from the server etc. Neo4j has internally a unique id for all nodes. Is there a way to retrieve this id from neo4j and assign it to my object id?

I've read, that this is generally a bad idea since the id's could be reused from neo4j after a node has been removed. But since the object with this node id was this node, the id doesn't exist anymore for me also. So I don't see what stands against this.

Otherwise I can use GUID I know about that way.

Comment: Suppose something other than your application (like the neo4j browser) deletes a node and then creates another node (that happens to get the same native ID as the deleted node), and suppose your application now gets that new node -- then your application would have two node objects with the same `id`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the internal node Id with the following cypher:

```
CREATE (e:Example)
RETURN id(e) as id
```

Neo4j also has the `randomUUID()` procedure available for such scenarios. Check the [documentation](https://neo4j.com/docs/cypher-manual/current/functions/scalar/#functions-randomuuid) for more information.

```
CREATE (e:Example{id:randomUUID()})
RETURN e.id as id
```